# Plotly Dash URL routing to id in current page

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I am building a webapp querying test results from a sqlite database (# or records in the 1,000s).
Most of the time I will have results from > 10 different test methods for a given comparison. Results are displayed as bar graphs, scatter graphs, pictures, etc. It makes for long, linear page and a lot of vertical scrolling before reaching the information your looking for (but at the same time having everything at the same place is what I am aiming at).
To limit the scrolling, I managed to put a sidebar and am trying to make hyperlinks in the sidebar jump to the section I want to navigate to.
Here is my question: I looked at [url routing](https://dash.plotly.com/urls) documentation and at [this thread](https://community.plotly.com/t/basic-question-on-url-routing/34154), but could not find a way
there to link to a given id=foo in current page. Like it would be done with href=#foo in html.
Is there a way to link to a location in current page with dash?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can do it just like in html. Here is a small example app,

```
import dash
import dash_html_components as html

app = dash.Dash()
app.layout = html.Div([html.P("Hello world."), html.A("To the end", href="#end")] + [html.Br()]*100 +
                      [html.P("Goodbye world", id="end")])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server()
```

Comment: Thanks, it's perfectly works fine when uses html.A("To the end", href="#end") but when i use this with dash bootstrap component dbc.NavLink("To the end", href="#end") it doesn't work.

Comment: It was not clear from the question that you were seeking an answer for the dbc.NavLink component specifically. However, it should work for this component too. Note that for this particular component you must set the external_link flag to true, i.e. the code should be dbc.NavLink("To the end", href="#end", external_link=True).